# PHP MySQL PDO Update not working

Tags: php, pdo

This is driving me absolutely crazy, I've rewritten it several times and still no go. My insert function works perfectly fine. I have no idea what I'm overlooking, anything you could suggest that might help would be extremely appreciated.

```
  function update($table, $data, $idName='id')
  {
      if(empty($data) || !is_array($data))
           return false;

      $columns = $values = array();
      foreach($data as $key => $val)
           $columns[] = "$key=:$key";
      $columns = makeCSL($columns, false);

      try {
           $qStr = "UPDATE $table SET $columns WHERE $idName=:id";
           echo $qStr;
           $query = $this->dbHandle->prepare($qStr);
           foreach($data as $key => $val)
                $query->bindParam("':$key'", $val, PDO::PARAM_STR);
           $query->execute();
      } catch(PDOException $e) {
           $this->errCode = $e->getCode();
           $this->errInfo = $e->errorInfo[2];
      }
  }
```

Comment: What is the `makeCSL` function doing?

Comment: What's missing here is a concise description of the problem. 'not working' just doesn't convey anything. Do you have an error message? Have you checked your server error logs?

Comment: @scrowler Presumably it stands for Make Comma-Separated List, so it just does something like `implode(',', $columns)`.

Comment: @scrowler It generates a CSL (Comma-separated List).

Comment: @MikeW No error messages at all. PDO thinks that it's working just fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it working with the following code

```
  function update($table, $data, $idName="id")
  {
      if(empty($data) || !is_array($data))
           return false;

      $columns = array();
      foreach($data as $key => $val)
           $columns[] = "$key=:$key";
      $columns = makeCSL($columns, false);

      try {
           $query = $this->dbHandle->prepare("UPDATE $table SET $columns WHERE $idName=:id");
           $query->execute($data);
      } catch(PDOException $e) {
           $this->errCode = $e->getCode();
           $this->errInfo = $e->errorInfo[2];
      }
  }
```

Comment: Could you explain what you changed?

Comment: Instead of using bindParam or bindValue I set it to simply use keys. The code creates a list of the keys based on the array values and passes those through the SQL query, including the ID key.

Comment: You still have two uses of `:id` placeholders, I'm surprised it works.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, I'm aware of that. Pretty sure it's just because PDO has some error checking and just drops duplicates and keeps the first, or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems.

First, you shouldn't put quotes around the placeholder being bound. Second, you need to use `bindValue`, because `bindParam` binds to a reference, so everything will be bound to the value of `$val` from the last time through the loop. And third, you don't have a binding for `:id`.

So it should be:

```
foreach($data as $key => $val) {
    if ($key != 'id') {
        $columns[] = "$key=:$key";
    }
}

...

foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
    $query->bindValue(":$key", $val, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
```

Comment: The id variable is in the data array. I tried switching to bindValue and still no go. No errors are thrown or anything, it just simply does not update the database. :(

Comment: In that case, you were ending up with two `:id` placeholders in your query, one in the `SET` clause and the other in the `WHERE` clause. Duplicate placeholders aren't allowed. See my update, which skips that field when creating the `SET` clause.

Comment: I had that set as well, but it still wasn't working. I submitted an answer that works for me perfectly.